$T_6$ spaces that aren't submetrizable
Let $X$ be a topological space.
$X$ is submetrizable if the topology contains a coarser topology which is metrizable (the topology on the space is induced by a metric).
Equivalently, $X$ is submetrizable if there is a continuous injective map from $X$ into some metrizable space.
I wanted to find examples of spaces that aren't submetrizable but that verify certain separation axioms. I have found some of the examples that I wanted to find. But, when I add the property $G_{\delta}$, I haven't been able to find some examples. I wanted to ask if anyone knows an example of a $T_6$ space that isn't submetrizable.

This has been answered here.

Thank you, Ulli.

In the comments, Ulli has posted a link to the answer (of Henno Brandsma) of the question.
My comments on that answer:
Here it can be found the proof of the following theorem: Compact spaces with $G_{\delta}$ diagonal are metrizable.
Here, I have attempted to prove the result posted as a comment (also by Henno Brandsma) in that same answer:
Theorem: Let $(X, \tau)$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then, $(X, \tau)$ doesn't have a strictly coarser Hausdorff topology.
Let $(X, \tau)$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let's suppose that there exists a coarser topology on $X$, let's denote as $\tau'$, which is Hausdorff. We have that $\tau' \subseteq \tau$ and we want to see that $\tau' = \tau$.
Let $C$ be a proper closed non-empty set in $(X, \tau)$, then $C$ is compact in $(X, \tau)$.
Let $x \in X \setminus C$ and let $y \in C$, as $(X, \tau')$ is Hausdorff, then there exist $U_y$ and $V_y$ disjoint open sets in $(X, \tau')$ such that $x \in U_y$ and $y \in V_y$.
We have that $C \subseteq \bigcup_{y \in C}V_y$. As $\tau' \subseteq \tau$ and $C$ is compact in $(X, \tau)$, then, there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n\subseteq C$ such that $C \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^nV_{y_i}$. Note that $\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_{y_i}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $(X, \tau')$ verifying that $\bigcap_{i=1}^nU_{y_i} \subseteq X \setminus C$. Therefore, $X \setminus C \in \tau'$, i.e., $C$ is closed in $(X, \tau')$.
We conclude that $\tau' = \tau$.
Note: $R_1$ compact spaces that aren't indiscrete have a strictly coarser $R_1$ topology (the indiscrete space on the respective set where the space is defined on). Note that points that are topologically distinguishable could be topologically indistinguishable in a coarser topology.

In the answer of the linked post, Henno Brandsma used, indeed, that (countably) compact spaces with a $G_\delta$ diagonal are metrizable. However, in the following comment, he used a much simpler argument avoiding this theorem.

Nice result in Henno Brandsma's comment: Compact Hausdorff submetrizable spaces are metrizable.  Hence the double arrow space (split interval) is an example of T6 space that is not submetrizable.

Yeah, we will add it to $\pi$-Base.

A quicker proof: $ id: (X, \tau) \rightarrow (X, \tau^\prime)$ is continuous and bijective, hence a homeomorphism. Hence $\tau = \tau^\prime$.
